# Is there a faster/more efficient way to call different functions, than using if-else statements, depending on a variable's value range?

Tags: javascript, performance, if-statement

As part of a little game I am making, I have an `enemy` object which fires projectiles at the `character` object, controlled by the player. The `enemy` has an `hp` attribute with a value of `10000`, and as this value depletes, I want the projectile-firing patterns to change. This is my current situation:

```
this.fireOnce = function(){ ... }
this.fireRandomly = function(){ ... }
this.fireAtTarget = function(){ ... }
this.fireWave = function(){ ... }

this.beginFire = function(){
    if(hp<3000){
        this.fireWave();
    }
    else if(hp<5000){
        this.fireAtTarget();
    }
    else if(hp<9000){
        this.fireRandomly();
    }
    else{
        this.fireOnce();
    }

    setTimeout(beginFire, 500);

}
```

The main loop already has enough complexity already, and things get laggy when many projectiles are on the screen. My concern about if-else statements derives from something my professor said about them being fairly expensive (I can't remember the context though so I could be wrong).

During the creation of this little game, I've used the above structure several times for different matters, and considering the functions get called several times each second, I assume that it takes its toll on the game's performance.

One possibility in an other situation would be to use an object containing the functions, but since we are talking about integer ranges, I can't think of something to use as a key.

Comment: This looks a log like premature optimisation. If you find you have performance issues, go looking for cures. The code seems simple and easy to maintain, don't obfuscate it with complexity to cure a problem that may not even exist or is elsewhere.

Comment: You could take the "lowest" three functions and put them in an Array where the first function takes the first three slots, the second takes the next two, and the third takes the next four, giving a total of 9. Then divide `hp` by 1000 and `Math.floor()` that result to get the index. Then use an `||` to get the last function if it's `>= 9000`.

Comment: ...like this: `(funcs[Math.floor(hp/1000)] || fireOnce).call(this)`, but heed @RobG's comments about premature optimization. I don't know if it'll help or hinder things. You could replace `Math.floor()` with `~~` for a possible, but not guaranteed, optimization, like this: `(funcs[~~(hp/1000)] || fireOnce).call(this)`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5v9fbc95/

Comment: Thanks a lot. Optimizing this code would actually help in optimizing other pieces as well, since many follow the same pattern. Would firing a property event whenever `hp` is changed help in avoiding unecesary if statements? (i'm not sure if such an event exists in javascript)

Comment: @squint Thanks a lot, your example was clear and on point :) However what's this syntax `~~` ? It's the first time I've seen it.

Comment: @Alan: It's a trick, to force truncation to integer by applying the bitwise "NOT" operation `~`, then "NOT" the values back again with another `~`. Don't use tricks like this. Write self-explanatory code.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition: I agree that it's not a great approach in general, but there are times and places for ugly code too, like if you can demonstrate an actual performance benefit in a spot that truly needs it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always beware premature optimisation, however you might want to make your code a bit clearer (though there is nothing wrong with the OP). You can create more concise code if you can reduce the logic to generate a single value, then use that value as a key to call a method.

E.g. if the break points were 3000, 6000 and 9000 then the code can be derived from `hp / 3000`:

```js
function Bot(){
  // sorted by value
  this.fireWave = function(){     // hp <= 3000
    console.log('fireWave');
  }
  this.fireAtTarget = function(){ // hp <= 6000
    console.log('fireAtTarget');
  }
  this.fireRandomly = function(){ // hp <= 9000
    console.log('fireRandomly');
  }
  this.fireOnce = function(){     // hp > 9000
    console.log('fireOnce');
  }
    
  // Method names in order
  var methods = ['fireOnce','fireWave','fireAtTarget','fireRandomly'];
    
  this.beginFire = function(){
    this[methods[Math.ceil(hp / 3000)] || methods[0]]();
    // Don't do this for testing
    // setTimeout(beginFire, 500);
  }
}

var bot = new Bot();
var hp = 0;

for (var i=0; i<10; i++) {
  // Randomly set hp to value between 0 and 1200
  hp = Math.random()*12000 | 0;
  console.log('hp: ' + hp);
  bot.beginFire();
}
```

So as long as you can determine a simple mathematic expression to calculate the code, then you can easily determine the method to call.

You could also have a helper method (possibly on the constructor) that does the logic to determine the method to call, like:

```
function getFireMethod() {
  return hp < 3000? 'fireWave' :
         hp < 5000? 'fireAtTarget' :
         hp < 9000? 'fireRandomly' : 
                    'fireOnce';
}
```

Which is clear and concise, but again may not have any perceptible impact on performance either way.

In any case, you will need to do testing across a variety of clients to determine whether there is any useful performance gain. Also, include comments in the code to describe the logic.

Comment: I don't think that either of these suggestions are in any way "clearer", and they're certainly not as easy to maintain and/or debug.

Comment: Thank you. In the end is a mathematical expression faster than if statements? Because there are times it's very hard to find it, and i need to be certain it's worth my time. (For this particular or any other problem for that matter)

Comment: As a rule of thumb, a mathematical expression is faster if it takes less time to evaluate the mathematical expression than it takes to evaluate all conditions in the if-statement. For the given expression, and the given number of conditions in the if statement, this seems doubtful, but if you have many conditions that simplify into a simple mathematical expression this can be faster, though the difference will only matter if the code is executed millions of times every second.

Answer (score 1):

"fairly expensive" is a relative term. Yes, a conditional branch, if the condition's value is not predicted, can easily cost dozens of clock cycles, meaning that a single CPU can only execute millions of if statements per second.

To verify this, run the following script in the java script runtime you target:

```
let odd = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) {
    if (i % 2) odd++;
}
odd;
```

This code executes one billion if statements. In Chrome, it takes about 3 seconds on my machine. Firefox is slower, but still executes one million if statements in about 0.2 seconds, and IE one million if statements in 0.1 seconds.

To conclude, there is no modern JavaScript runtime where a few if statements per second would result in a measurable, let alone human-perceptible, degradation of performance. Whatever the source of your performance problem, it's not your use of if statements.

Comment: Thanks! That remark my proffesor made kept bugging me for a while. It's just that with every little new feature i add, I also unwillingly add a bunch of if statements in the game loop, so i had to ask if there's a better way.